# JDBC drivers are not getting registered automatically even though it contains service directory with java.sql.Driver?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am running a simple program which makes JDBC connection with mysql. I am using 5.0.8 connector jar (mysql driver). As i read about JDBC 4 service mechanism we dont need to call `Class.forname("..")` to register driver. I am trying this without it.

```
Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"", "root", "root");
        System.out.println("Is Connection closed: "+conn.isClosed());

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Error occurred while getting connection because of : " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);`
    } finally {
        if (conn != null){
            conn.close();
            System.out.println("Is Connection closed: "+conn.isClosed());
        }
    }
```

But when i execute this it give me below error:

_No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db

Also tried with mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar

Comment: You shouldn't need `Class.forName` anymore, but you certainly still need for your MySQL driver JAR to be on the classpath.  So...is that driver on your classpath?

Comment: Yes i have added that in class path of my project

Comment: Well the error message seems to be saying otherwise.  How are you doing your build?

Comment: I have added jar in referenced libraries on my eclipse project and i am simply running a main program.

Comment: Also tried exporting the program as jar and running it from command line 
with java -cp "TestConnection.jar;lib/*" com.TestConnection

to explicitly specify class path while running program 

Here /lib directory contains mysql driver jar.

Comment: Version 5.0.8 is 11 years old, try a more recent version of the driver. And please update your answer with a [mcve]. That is: include the full class, and the commandline you execute. Don't use comments to provide pertinent information.

Comment: Also, you say that driver has services directory, but MySQL Connector/J 5.0.8 does not contain a service definition (the file `/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` does not exist)

Comment: Is this Service Mechanism depends on java environment (JDK) ? Do i have to make any changes to enable this behavior?

Comment: You need a JDBC 4 or higher JDBC driver, you also need at least Java 6 (which introduced the driver autoloading). And of course, you need to check the actual requirements of your driver, for example a driver compiled for Java 8 cannot be loaded in Java 7 (but a driver compiled for Java 6 can be loaded in Java 7 and higher).

Answer (score 0):

Automatic driver loading only works if the driver jar contains service definition. MySQL Connector/J 5.0.8 is not JDBC 4 compliant and does **not** contain a service definition (`META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`) required for automatic driver loading. So, automatic driver loading cannot work with version 5.0.8.

You will need to use a newer version of MySQL Connector/J (eg 5.1.47 or 8.0.12).

Comment: Hi Mark thanks, But when i open a mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar i can se that there is META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver a file inside a jar.

Comment: Tried with mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar but still getting the same error

Comment: Then you need to edit your question and show exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: I earlier asked for all relevant information: _And please update your answer with a [mcve]. That is: include the full class, and the commandline you execute. Don't use comments to provide pertinent information._ You haven't done that.